# find maximum number of elements with same difference

Tags: arrays, integer, max

Given unsorted array of integers find the **maximum number of elements**, that when taken and **sorted in a non descending order**, every two adjacent numbers have the same difference.

for example: Given the array [3, 4, 1, 5, 4, 7],
you can take the elements 1, 4, 7 with difference 3,
or **you can take 1, 3, 5, 7. thus the answer is : 4**;

my first guess was to sort the array, and try some kind of greedy algorithm. of course there is the  brut force solution of compering every 2 elements but i believe there is a more optimal solution